# How to include a List of Symbols and Abbreviations in the List of Tables?

Tags: table-of-contents

in my large document I have a List of Tables, on page xi, and a List of Symbols and Abbreviations that starts on page xiii. Shortly after that arabic numbering starts for the regular content pages.

Right now the List of Tables is autogenerated and includes some tables from the regular content pages, listing their names and pages' arabic numerals.

I would like to expand this List of Tables to also include the List of Symbols and Abbreviations, complete with its roman numerals. How can I do this?

Comment: Please edit your question by adding a minimal example (a short working piece of code that reproduces your problem). Then it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: Figured it out, it required this command: \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{List of Abbreviations}

Comment: You can self-answer your question. However, I'm asking why this should go in the list of tables and not in the table of contents.

Comment: To answer your question - I'm listing the symbols and abbreviations in both the ToC (Table of Contents) and LoT (List of Tables) actually, since (a) these symbols and abbreviations were structured / laid out as a table, so it fits in the LoT's scope, and (b) the LoT is typically quite empty, so the more I can add the better... I've got over 40 figures in this document, but only a handful of tables :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, it required this command:

```
\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{List of Abbreviations}
```